# AWS integration ios issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, aws-mobilehub

[image][image][image][image]I followed the instructions on AWS and I got the following error messages when I try to build the app.

The app is built with Swift 3 and XCode 8.3.3

Error messages are:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSGetEndpointAttributesInput", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSSubscribeInput", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)


"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSSetEndpointAttributesInput", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)


"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSLambdaInvoker", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSCloudLogic.o)


"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNS", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)


"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)


"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSSNSUnsubscribeInput", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)


"_AWSSNSErrorDomain", referenced from:
  ___88-[AWSPushManager interceptApplication:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:]_block_invoke.235 in AWSMobileHubHelper(AWSPushManager.o)


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

AWSMobileHubHelper.framework should be linked with the application. Add the missing frameworks in the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section in XCode.

Comment: Did you add the Sdk/Aws folder and AmazonAws/  folder to XCode project?
You can do this by clicking "Add files to..." by right clicking on your Xcode project and add these two folders to the project.

Comment: Yes. Added the screenshot above to show it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to have it **ONLY** in the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`.
Try removing it from the `Embedded Binaries` section.

Comment: Thanks Lisa but this doesn't work either. Please see screenshots above.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so the solution that worked for me was the following:
in the Podfile I added the following : 
pod 'AWSCognito'
pod 'AWSCognitoIdentityProvider'
pod 'AWSLambda'
pod 'AWSMachineLearning'
pod 'AWSMobileAnalytics'
pod 'AWSS3'
pod 'AWSSES'
pod 'AWSSNS'
You can add whichever give you an error message. 
I have reached out to AWS and got not answer on their example page. 
Hope this helps someone.